# Is the radical of an algebra a maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have a symmetric bilinear form $k[G] \times k[G] \rightarrow k$ for some finite group $G$ such that it is nondegenerate. My professor says that because it is nondegenerate we have that the Jacobson Radical of $k[G] = 0.$ I am confused as to how he concluded this. Because it is nondegenerate we have that the radical of $k[G], rad(k[G]) = 0.$ So is the radical a maximal ideal in $k[G]?$ If so, I understand. If not, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have misunderstood.   *Every* group ring using a field and a finite group admits a nondegenerate bilinear form like this, since they are [Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_algebra), but many of them have nonzero Jacobson radicals.

For example example, if $F$ is the field of $p$ elements and $G$ is a finite $p$ group, $F[G]$ is local, so the Jacobson radical is maximal and nonzero.

Are you sure the instructor want referring to the radical *of the bilinear form* which would definitely be zero because that is the definition of nondegeneracy?

Comment: Your response helped me understand. Thank you!